# How does spring annotations select class to inject?

Tags: spring-annotations

I have downloaded a Spring annotations example but I cant see how it chooses which class to inject, heres the code and configuration.
First a couple of implementations of the IWriter interface (not shown)

```
package writers;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class NiceWriter implements IWriter {
    public void writer(String s)    {
        System.out.println("Nice Writer - " + s);
    }
}


package writers;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Writer implements IWriter{
    public void writer(String s)    {
        System.out.println("Writer - "+s);
    }
}

package testbean;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import writers.IWriter;

    @Service
    public class SpringBeanWithDI{
        private IWriter writer;

        @Autowired
        public void setWriter(IWriter writer)   {
            this.writer = writer;
        }

        public void run()   {
            String s = "This is my test";
            writer.writer(s);
        }
    }
```

The test bean :-

```
package main;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import testbean.SpringBeanWithDI;

public class TestBean  {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/beans.xml");
        BeanFactory factory = context;
        SpringBeanWithDI test = (SpringBeanWithDI) factory.getBean("springBeanWithDI");
        test.run();
    }
}
```

and the beans.xml file :-

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="testbean" />
  <context:component-scan base-package="Writers" />

</beans>
```

All very simple but why does it always inject the 'Writer' implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

From the documenation I found this :-

"For a fallback match, the bean name is considered as a default qualifier value. This means that the bean may be defined with an id "main" instead of the nested qualifier element, leading to the same matching result.

However, note that while this can be used to refer to specific beans by name, @Autowired is fundamentally about type-driven injection with optional semantic qualifiers. This means that qualifier values, even when using the bean name fallback, always have narrowing semantics within the set of type matches; they do not semantically express a reference to a unique bean id."
So in my example the field 'writer' is used to find a class called 'Writer'.

private IWriter writer;

Clever ! (maybe too clever!)